# Groovy - Appending to list available only via getter-setter

Tags: list, groovy, getter-setter

In a Groovy class I want to expose internal `String` property as a `List` through getters and setters. I want the property to behave just like a regular list property to which I can add element using `obj.list << newElement`. However it does not work and I have to use work-around `obj.list = obj.list << newElement`.

Is there any other way to do the trick in Groovy? Any method to be implemented in the class, that will be called when `<<` operator is used?

Code example:

```
class Test {

    String internal = 'a,b,c'

    List getList() {
        return internal .split(',')
    }

    void setList(List list) {
        internal = list.join(',')
    }

}

def t = new Test()
println t.internal          // a,b,c
println t.list              // [a, b, c]
t.list << 'd'               // this does not work! does not add new element
println t.list              // [a, b, c] 
t.list = t.list << 'd'      // work-around that works
println t.list​​              // [a, b, c, d]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
class Test {
    String internal = 'a,b,c'

    List getList() {
        def list = internal.split(',') as List

        // this will override so:
        // << 'd'       becomes appendToList(['d'])
        // << ['e','f'] becomes appendToList(['e','f'])
        list.metaClass.leftShift = { def x ->
            this.appendToList([x].flatten())
        } 

        return list
    }

    void appendToList(List list) {
        internal = internal + "," + list.join(',')
    }

    void setList(List list) {
        internal = list.join(',')
    }
}
```

Note it handles both cases of (a) one item (b) a list of items

```
def t = new Test()
t.list << 'd'
assert ['a','b','c','d'] == t.list
t.list << ['e','f']
assert ['a','b','c','d','e','f'] == t.list
t.list = ['x','y']
assert ['x', 'y'] == t.list
```

Comment: Yes it does work, however now `t.list = ['a','c']` will not do what would be expected. But it is easily fixed by renaming this method `setList` to `appendToList` and providing `setList` as in initial example. If you could update your answer including this, I will accept it. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code,

```
Test t = new Test()
 List list = t.getList()
list << 'd'

println list.dump()
```

Comment: This will print the correct list, but it will not change the value for the `internal` property. The main idea here is to keep implementation details of a class unchanged, but to provide new interface to the outside world.

Comment: Internal property is your string not a list, how you can data in that. You can declare another property as  a List and store data in that, which you can expose to outsiders

Comment: I could declare another list property, but appending element to that list would not trigger synchronization with the string, and will result in incorrect behaviour of the whole class.

Comment: You need to declare a list to store the data, the list you are getting printed from object is temporarily used by system to return data only, which don't have longer reference.

Comment: print t.list.getClass() what it is printing